# SQL query using where clause of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Lets say one for actors where data the column is actorid and each row has values like 101, 102, 103, 104.

Now I have another table named work. It counts how many times a user worked on something provided they are over 18. its name is workactor and it has three columns, actorid, age and typeofwork.

Now I want to create a query that counts how many different items of work each user did. I have been able to do that using the following query:

```
SELECT a.actorid, COUNT(wa.actor_id) AS total
FROM actors a LEFT JOIN
     workactor wa
     ON wa.actorid = a.actorid where wa.age>18
GROUP BY a.actorid;
```

Now although this does count each type of work for every actor, it doesn't show 0 for any actor who is there in actors table but not in workactor table. I don't know what the issue is.

When I remove wa.age>18 it works fine, but i need that condition also.

Answer (score 2):

you need to have that where condition as part of your join condition :

```
SELECT a.actorid, COUNT(wa.actor_id) AS total
FROM actors a 
LEFT JOI workactor wa
  ON wa.actorid = a.actorid 
  and wa.age>18
GROUP BY a.actorid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing left join, wa.age may be null if the actor is not in the workactor table.

```
SELECT a.actorid, COUNT(wa.actor_id) AS total
FROM actors a LEFT JOIN
     workactor wa
     ON wa.actorid = a.actorid where (wa.age is null or wa.age>18)
GROUP BY a.actorid;
```